# Pandas timeseries, binning on one columnn and accumulate time spent in the bins

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, binning

I have a problem regarding binning using pandas!
Here is a simplified example:
I have a dataframe df

```
     time  speed
0    0.1     20
1    0.2     20
2    0.3     30
3    0.4     30
4    0.5     40
5    0.6     40
6    0.7     40
7    0.8     40
8    0.9     50
9    1.0     50
10   1.1     60
11   1.2     70
12   1.3     80
13   1.4     80
14   1.5     80
15   1.6     80
16   1.7     40
17   1.8     40
18   1.9     40
```

Here is what I want to do:
I would like to bin the data on speed, like bins = [0,20,40,60,80].
I would then like to have the time column values binned according to the speed-binning.
After that I would like to accumulate the time in the bins and plot a histogram.
Please, help

Comment: Have you tried playing around with [`df.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [117]: binned_time = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.speed, bins=[0,20,40,60,80]))['time']                                                                                                                                                                                        

In [118]: binned_time.sum()
Out[118]: 
speed
(0, 20]     0.30
(20, 40]    3.30
(40, 60]    1.11
(60, 80]    1.24
Name: time, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Almost there!!, I should have stated that the time column is a time series. So is there a way to accumulate the time spent in each bin?

Comment: This depends on how time is represented. If as timestamps, then i assume you want to subtract the highest and lowest timestamp in a bin. In case time columnn are timedelta objects, sum() can still be used.

Comment: I've got a speed signal that is varying over time, short updated description above. I'm not sure if subtracting the highest from the lowest in that bin will give me the accumulated time in that speed bin.

Comment: In that case high-low is not ok. You need to decide how to compute time/bin and than translate to pandas.

Comment: I guess I need help with that, any ideas?

Comment: Solved it by multiplying sampling frequency times the count in each bin!!

Comment: Is it possible to get the average value of each bin?